# Getting Client IP address in WCF with wsDualHttpBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I am using the following code in my service

```
public class HeartBeat : IHeartBeat
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
        MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
        RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint =
            prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
        string ip = endpoint.Address;

        return "IP address is: " + ip;
    }
}
```

I noticed that if my web config is:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
</protocolMapping>
```

I can get the IP address successfully. However, if i use dual http binding like this:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="wsDualHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
</protocolMapping>
```

I am getting a null return. Is there any other way to get IP address of client in wsDualHttpBinding? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out using @Neel

```
public class HeartBeat : IHeartBeat
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
        MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
        RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint =
            prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
        string ip = endpoint.Address;

        EndpointAddress test = OperationContext.Current.Channel.RemoteAddress;
        IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.Channel.RemoteAddress.Uri.Host);

        foreach (IPAddress ip2 in ipHostEntry.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip2.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LocalIPadress: " + ip);
                return ip2.ToString();
            }
        }

        return "IP address is: " +  System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.Channel.RemoteAddress.Uri.Host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Address` property appears empty in case of `wsDualHttpBinding`.

The `RemoteEndpointMessageProperty` uses the `HttpApplication.Request.UserHostAddress` to return the IP.
however, the `HttpContext` is not available with `WSDualHttpBinding`, causing a "Request is not available in the context" exception.

You can try to access host property like below for dual channel.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endpoint.Address))
{
    string clientIpOrName = System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.Channel.RemoteAddress.Uri.Host;
}
```

Comment: Spot on dude.. It is working.. However I am getting PC name instead of IP address. anyway to resolve this?